# Google sign is not working iOS Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, google-signin

I am enabled Google Sign in for my iOS App, it was working perfect before updating xcode, but after updating it is not working. I followed [Google developer link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?configured=true&ver=swift) for enabling this. But i am failed to find actual problem. Here is my code :-

// AppDelegate.swift

```
   import Google

  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate
 {

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 // Initialize sign-in
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
   GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "XXXXXXXXXX-5meoeobXXXXXXXglsin1u01XXXXXX8.apps.googleusercontent.com"

 }

   func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {


        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                                 sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                                 annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

   }


    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

   }
```

// LOGIN CONTROLLER

```
    class loginController : UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate{

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

           GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
           GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

  }


   @IBAction func googleSignInButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

    print("google login is clicked")
   }


   func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

       if let err = error {
        print(err)
        print("Error in Fetching the information-----\(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
    else {
  // --- User data

          user.sharedInstance.googleid = user.userID
          user.sharedInstance.name = user.profile.name

          user.sharedInstance.email = user.profile.email

   }
    }

   I tried a lot of link, but don't work for me. Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: You declared delegate in appdelegate so just write this method into appdelegate also. Only write delegate methods dont write any logic in it and try it

Comment: I tried this one in App Delegate but was not work for me.  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {}.

Comment: Can you send me your demo? I will check it and return back to you with answer. @m

Comment: Okay, what you want actually. I didn't get it. My all code is in question.

Comment: just your demo, you actually create

Comment: Actually i was enabled in my existing app, it was working perfectly before i updated Xcode 9.1. Signin delegate method is not called.